# Type of power converter to be used for both AC and DC use

Tags: power-supply, ac, dc, adapter

What kind of power adapter that I need to use to supply power for a DC motor of a fan and also an AC heating element? These two components will also connect with Arduino.

Is any of these power adapter can be used?
[image: Option 1]

[image: Option 2]

Thank you for helping..

Answer (score 2):

You need a DC power supply for the fan.

A heating element can be powered from AC or DC. It won't care.

> Is any of these power adapter can be used?

Maybe. Maybe not.

If you are studying mechatronics you'll need to learn that you can't use random power supplies on random electrical components. You have to match them properly. This means reading the specifications for each and confirming that they are suitable.